Python Telegram Bot does not reply to messages sent by another bot
I'm programming two telegram bots in python.
The first is used by users in private chat who enter data via keyboard and attach a video. Subsequently, the bot sends a report of the one entered by the users to a private telegram group and writes some data to a database (including the ID of the report message just sent).
The second bot among the various functions has one that should respond to the report message sent by the previous bot with a text.
The problem I encounter is that the bot is unable to reply to messages sent by the other bot but can only do so with messages that I have sent or that it has sent itself.
I tried to turn off the privacy mode on botfather but nothing changed, could anyone help me?
P.S. both bots have administrator permissions on the group

That's not possible, bots can never read messages from other bots.
You'll have to let the second both trigger on something else. You could for example read it from the database or implement another way of sending 'events' to the second bot.

The bots only can recive messages from other bots in channels. Not in groups nor private chats.
